# MySQL full text search, joining and ordering both by relevancy and an integer, using PHP and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, full-text-search

I have two tables:

- `Meta` has all information about an ID.
- `Posters` has a many-to-one relationship to Meta by movie_id (many posters to one movie, sometimes)

Now I want to create a full text search using PHP and PDO to prepare the statement and return results first by relevancy, then by year.

So if 'test' is searched against:

```
test, 2
test, 1
testy test, 1
test me, 1
lets test, 1
```

I want the 'test, 2' to show first followed by the second test, then most relevant searched bases on whatever full text thinks is relevant? The order above is a good start.

This is what I have created so far

```
$query = "SELECT Meta.id, Meta.year, Posters.filename, Meta.title,
              FROM Meta INNER JOIN Posters ON Meta.id = Posters.movie_id
              WHERE MATCH(Meta.title)
              AGAINST(:term IN BOOLEAN MODE)
              ORDER BY Meta.year DESC
              LIMIT 50";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':term', $term);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This returns them only by year - all text relevancy is lost?

I have seen other pretty complicated examples that were very hard for me to follow - and they didn't include any JOINs which made it more difficult for me.

Ideally I would like a single query.

Edit: for clarification, when I am searching

```
the girl with the dragon tattoo
```

the results are

```
nowhere girl
how to train your dragon 2
how to train your dragon
gone girl
(several movies with 'girl' keyword in them)
The girl with the dragon tattoo
```

Notice how the movie I actually searched for is last, and "nowhere girl" is first because it is the most recent.

Comment: Could you perhaps be more explicit about what is being returned versus what you want returned?

Comment: sure - ill add it to the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have 2 problems here. First, if you match `IN BOOLEAN MODE`, you will always get a relevance of `1.0`.

Next, you don't have any relevance because you're not making use of it.  You need to add it to your query using something like:

```
$query = "SELECT Meta.id, Meta.year, Posters.filename, Meta.title,
              MATCH(Meta.title) AGAINST(:term) AS Relevance
              FROM Meta INNER JOIN Posters ON Meta.id = Posters.movie_id
              WHERE MATCH(Meta.title)
              AGAINST(:term IN BOOLEAN MODE)
              ORDER BY Relevance DESC, Meta.year DESC
              LIMIT 50";
```